# On Riemann integrability and sequence of functions

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:[0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be such that:

$$f_n(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix} 
x^2 \sin 1/x^2 & ,x \neq 0\\  
0 &, 1/n <x =0 
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Prove that $f$ (limit function of $f_n$) is continuous and differentiable but $f'$ is not Riemann integrable.

**Question:** Is the exercise correct or not? The second branch of the function is what bothers me. If it is correct how can I find the limit function $f$?

Comment: What do you mean by $\frac 1 n <x =0$?

Comment: I don't know what the author means by this notation. The exercise is written exactly as I have written it. 

However I have a strong belief that the function should be:

$$f_n(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix} 
x^2 \sin 1/x^2 & ,x \neq 0\\  
1/n &, x =0 
\end{matrix}\right.$$

If so,then everything goes well... and it is a trivial one (at least to me)

Comment: As it is written, it makes absolutely no sense, it is most surely a typing error. I guess your version is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming we indeed have

$$f_n(x)=\begin{cases}x^2\sin\dfrac1{x^2}&,\;\;x\neq 0\\{}\\\dfrac1n&,\;\;x=0\end{cases}$$

the limit function's clearly

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x^2\sin\dfrac1{x^2}&,\;\;x\neq 0\\{}\\\;\;\;\;\;0&,\;\;x=0\end{cases}$$

Since $\;\sin\dfrac1{x^2}\;$ bounded, we get both continuity and existence of derivative at zero, and thus everywhere (why?)

$$f(x)\xrightarrow[x\to 0]{}0\;,\;\;f'(x)=\lim_{x\to0}\;x\sin\frac1{x^2}=0$$

yet the derivative function of $\;f\;$:

$$f'(x)=\begin{cases}2x\sin\dfrac1{x^2}-\dfrac2x\cos\dfrac1{x^2}&,\;\;x\neq0\\{}\\\;\;\;\;0&,\;\;x=0\end{cases}$$

isn't Riemann integrable as it isn't bounded near zero .

Comment: Yes, if this is the correct exercise, that would be my answer. I would have written it myself down tomorro but thank you anyway!